# Composition of reflections equal iff $\bf a \perp b$

Tags: geometry

Given unit vectors $\bf a$ and $\bf b$, let $R_a$ be the reflection across the plane $\bf x\cdot a$ and similarly for $R_b$. Show that $R_aR_b=R_bR_a$ iff $\bf a \perp b$. (where $R_aR_b$ denotes a composition of respective reflections)

Here's the proof that I sketched and was wondering if it suffices?

Say $\bf a\perp b$, then both planes ($\bf x\cdot a$ and $\bf x\cdot b$) are orthogonal and hence they intersect. Since composition of reflections across two distinct intersecting planes is a rotation, so are $R_aR_b$ and $R_bR_a$.The angle of the rotation equals twice the angle between the intersecting planes - $\bf x\cdot a$ and $\bf x\cdot b$ - these two rotations are of equal angles and the result follows.

Now let $R_aR_b=R_bR_a$. Also, let R be an isometry such that $R({\bf 0})=\bf 0$. Then it preserves scalar products and thus

$$||R_aR_b||^2=||R_bR_a||^2=R_aR_b\cdot R_bR_a=R_a\cdot R_b$$

But then the angle between $R_a$ and $R_b$ is $0^\circ$ and this is possible iff $\bf a \perp b$

Comment: You can use that $R_a(v)=v-2\frac{v\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a$.

Answer (score 1):

Since reflections wrt $a$ and $b$ do not change $(span\{a,b\})^{\perp}$, you may consider the question on the 2D plane, then this is very easy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm self-learning math and I am trying to write a proof so that it would be both correct and understandable, and was wondering if the one I gave was like I've just described. forgot to mention, that the problem operates in $\mathbb R^3$

Answer (score 1):

The two planes are given as $a\cdot x=0$ and $b\cdot x=0$ (and not as "$x\cdot a$").

Concerning the first part: You have not really used the assumption $a\perp b$. It is true that the composition of reflection across intersecting planes is a rotation by twice the angle between the planes. But saying this one is not really taking care about the sense of this rotation, and this sense is reversed when the two reflections are interchanged. In order to understand what's going on look at the corresponding two-dimensional problem: One line of reflection is the $x$-axis, and the other line is an ascending line through the origin making an angle $\alpha\in\ \bigl]0,{\pi\over2}\bigr[\ $ with the $x$-axis. (This amounts to $a=(0,1,0)$ and $b=(-\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha,0)$ in the setting of your problem.)

Concerning the second part: Here you are way off. Note that $R_a$ and $R_b$ are not vectors, so there is no scalar product between them. I'd say that when you really have understood the first part it will be obvious to you that $R_aR_b\ne R_bR_a$ if $a\not\perp b$.

Comment: what I don't get is that if we presume that $R$ is the same reflection, but across two different orthogonal planes, why should we care about that 'sense' you were referring to? I thought, if we show that the angle of both rotations $R_aR_b$ and $R_bR_a$ is the same, then the end result should be the same.

Comment: By sense, he means clockwise and counterclockwise, essentially. As to why they are important, ask Hezekiah in the book of Isaiah; he said making the clock go forward (one sense) was too easy, and preferred the clock going backward (other sense), even though the magnitude of the angle of rotation was the same.